# Jmeter Incomplete response data

Tags: jmeter

new to Jmeter
i'm using Jmeter 2.11

Scenario:
I'm doing a simple login test on a https website, the website is protected by
posting some hidden dynamic variables during login therefore i need to use either
regular expression extacter or xpath extracter.

Issue:
 I used xpath extractor and had a valid xpath query however it always result in
no match. I checked the `View Results Tree` and took a look at the response data,
the reponse data shown is incomplete, there is a big part of the code missing
including the hidden fields.

what i tried:
checking the `retrieve all embedded resource` but nothing. 
My xpath extractor had `use tidy` and `Quiet` checked.

My idea:
With Jmeter not producing the full source, i think i need to extract the variable
somewhere else first then pass it into Jmeter but question is how to do it.

i'm know using selenium plugin in Jmeter could solve this issue but i wonder if
there's any solutions or suggestions around with Jmeter.

Thanks and have a nice day!

Edit:
This is what i would see in Jmeter

`<section class ="Content">  <form id="_myId" name="_myId"></form>`

```
 //Missing code that contains the variables

 </form> </section> </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

View Results Tree output is intentionally limited to 200 * 1024 bytes, if response will exceed this value it'll be truncated.

There is a parameter `view.results.tree.max_size` which specifies maximum response length that can be displayed. If you set it to zero response size check will be suppressed.

It can be done as follows:

1. Uncomment `#view.results.tree.max_size=0` line in "jmeter.properties" file (it lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)
2. Add `view.results.tree.max_size=0` line to `user.properties` file (the same location)
3. If you want to override this property just once it can be passed as a parameter to JMeter startup script as follows:

   ```
   jmeter -Jview.results.tree.max_size=0 ........
   ```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more details on JMeter Properties and ways of dealing with them.

Comment: thanks for the reply but it is not due to the size
(the body size in bytes is around 8000)

i checked and saw that only the form that contains the variables are missing.
 
one question, is it possible to 'hide' specific elements from jmeter?thanks Edit: I post an example.

Comment: There is no way to "hide" a part of response from JMeter. Perhaps it's present in a sub-sample. You can "tell" JMeter to temprarily save all the response data by adding `jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true` property to *jmeter.properties* or *user.properties* file